# Automating C++ build

Tags: c++, build, makefile, build-automation

I have a large and complex project that I build with Makefile on Linux. I need to port it to Windows and build it automatically. I've testcompiled it with tweaked versions of the make files via Cygwin on Windows but the Cygwin solution does not work for me in the long term. Is there any build automation tool for C++ that works equally well on both Linux and Windows?

Comment: E.g. ant, or cmake does. But sorry your question is OT!

Comment: What is the problem with cygwin make?

Comment: I have experienced different problems with Cygwin in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally recommend CMake for this. I have a moderately complex C++ project that I need to build in both g++ on linux and cygwin and VS2013, and CMake works quite well.

I started from https://github.com/SRombauts/cpp-skeleton and went from there. I did have to spend a few hours still learning CMake, but I feel like it was a good investment for cross platform.

A note on equally well -- CMake creates one VS project per build target. This is fine for building, but I would not say *developing* cross platform works equally well. This is not an issue for me -- everyone devs on Linux, but YMMV.

Good luck!